# Why does moment equilibrium at one point of an object mean the moment is at equilibrium for the whole system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statics

In class my prof said that when showing a system is at equilibrium it suffices to show that the moment at one point is zero. Why? Why does showing the moment at a point is zero imply the moment of the whole system is zero?

If I misunderstood him and the statement above isn't true, how do you show the system is at moment equilibrium at all points of the system? You obviously can't show the moment is at equilibrium for infinite points individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a direct consequence of equilibrium. It can be proved mathematically that proving the moment is zero at one point of a sytem in equilibrium ensures it is zero everywhere.

Have a look at the first two pages of [this](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~marghitu/MECH2110/C_5.pdf), you can find its proof